# Connecting Eclipse to TFS From Behind a proxy server

Tags: tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am having trouble connecting to the TFS Server using the eclipse tfs plugin from behind the proxy. I have configured my proxy settings correctly on the Eclipe->Preferences->Network Connections.

I read somewhere that I need to add my TFS credentials to the mac keychain ?. Could anyone explain me how to do that exactly ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having proxy configuration problems, it is recommend to check the "Override Default HTTP Proxy" option when configuring your Team Foundation Server in the plug-in for Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

for me it worked when I selected "Active Provider" as "Direct" in proxy settings of eclipse.I am using eclipse Kepler behind a corporate proxy.

You can change the proxy settings by going to windows-> preferences -> General -> Network Connections ->  Active Provider :(Drop-down as of now in Kepler) -> select Direct.